# Opencl 3D array indexing

Tags: opencl

I have 3D array (height, width, depth). My global worksize is (height * width * depth). and local work size is 1. In kernel code how I can get row offset and column offset?

I am doing the convolution operation in opencl. In C we do as follow,

```
// iterating through number of filters
for(c = 0; c < number_of_filters; c++)
{
    for(h = 0; h < out_height; h++)
    {
        for(w = 0; w < out_width; w++)
        {
           vert_start = h * stride;
           vert_end = vert_start + f_size ;
           hor_start = w * stride;
           hor_end = hor_start + f_size;

           sum = 0;
           for(c_f = 0; c_f < input_channel; c_f++)
           {
               for(h_f = vert_start; h_f < vert_end; h_f++)
               {
                   for(w_f = hor_start; w_f < hor_end; w_f++)
                   {
                      // computing convolution
                      sum = sum + 
                      (INPUT[(c_f * input_height * input_width) + (h * input_width) + w] * 
                       FILTER[(c_f * filt_height* filt_width) + (h_f * filt_width) + w_f)]);
                   }
               }
           }
           // storing result in output
           OUTPUT[(c * out_height * out_width) + (h * out_width) + w] = sum;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting how to get that row offset and column offset from image for convolution in opencl?

Comment: Creating `(height * width * depth)` number of workgroups of size 1 each sounds like something wrong to do. At least from performance point of view. Why not to have local size equals to power of 2 number or let environment to decide what's best?. Show us the code how you attempted to get row/column offset.

Comment: I am not getting how we can index our input array and input filter for convolution in opencl plz help me